# fake estimation of download time

Tags: http, firefox, download

I've been downloading files from some services that offers hosting. Very often, when I download as a free user Firefox (other browsers as well, haven't checked all, though) shows me that download speed is 400KB and 10 minutes remaining to the finish. This is BS, because it takes 45 minutes or more to download file and e.g. "1 minute 40 seconds remaning" is shown for a few seconds.

The present the user a higher speed. How do they do that? Is this HTTP protocol cheat or browser cheat? Why does Firefox show the wrong value?

Answer (score 2):

I've never experienced this, but then again I never use Firefox for downloading files.

That said, the remote server may be sending the files at high speed, but in short bursts of data that average out to their "free user" speed. Firefox may be seeing the speed at which data is downloaded during these bursts, rather than the overall average speed.

Comment: I am sure that is by design. e.g. https://rapidshare.com/ or http://uploaded.to/ do that. Since 95% user use browser to download they somehow manage to fake this estimation.

Comment: I think this is the case, at least for me. What I see is that download seems to get stuck for time to time until some time elapses and begin again.

Answer (score -2):

Many progress bars exist simply to make you feel better. For something like downloading a file, it is very difficult to estimate exactly.

How many packets get dropped and resent? What if bandwidth gets choked somewhere between your machine and the server? How much data needs to be sent? (for a file download, you could sent metadata first, but this can get complicated in many cases for many reasons).

These are all questions that are difficult or impossible to answer exactly, and they can be problematic to guess.

Bring in the idea that users [Don't perceive download times accurately anyway](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/actual-performance-perceived-performance.html), and the prospect of implementing an accurate progress bar is very unattractive. The easy way out is to make a progress bar that lies. Even the best implementations are just continuously revising a best guess, and there can be no guarantee about the accuracy of that guess.

The solution is to treat download-time estimates with some skepticism, and just be patient.

Comment: this is not about accurate estimation. It is on purpose higher be order or magnitude.

Comment: The browser lies about the time remaining, and this is why. The browser can't reliably determine the actual time remaining. Given the choice between having an often inaccurate progress bar, and no progress bar at all, users are happier with some feedback, regardless of how useful that feedback is. With this in mind, the tendency is towards progress bars that try to estimate, but often just make it up.

Comment: @Chris: No, Progress bars work very well on regular downloads nowadays. Sure, they may adapt if the rate drops half way through, but the question is about something different. It is about a special trick (possibly sending packets with content that fails CRC checks and thus get dropped) that is used by a few servers to frustrate free users, with the goal of making them pay for true high download rates. That is only remotely related to your very general remarks, stating how /all/ download bars are only guessing.

Answer (score -2):

Here's how to get the real bandwidth:

https://superuser.com/questions/356907/how-to-get-real-time-network-statistics-in-linux-with-kb-mb-bytes-format-and-for

make this script called "netbps" executable

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::HiRes;

my $reporting_interval = 10.0; # seconds
my $bytes_this_interval = 0;
my $start_time = [Time::HiRes::gettimeofday()];

while (<>) {
  if (/ length (\d+):/) {
    $bytes_this_interval += $1;
    my $elapsed_seconds = Time::HiRes::tv_interval($start_time);
    if ($elapsed_seconds > $reporting_interval) {
       my $bps = $bytes_this_interval / $elapsed_seconds;
       printf "%02d:%02d:%02d %10.2f Bps\n", (localtime())[2,1,0],$bps;
       $start_time = [Time::HiRes::gettimeofday()];
       $bytes_this_interval = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

sudo tcpdump -i wlan0 -l -e -n | ./netbps

All I can say is firefox is wrong.  This script gives you the good estimation of bytes per second.  It is about 1/4 that of firefox's estimation.  So new rule:  if it feels like firefox is giving a too short a time multiply by 4 to get the true time.